I want to implement a local cache in ASP.NET Core that automatically refreshes data after, say, 5 minutes
How can I create a simple and efficient local cache system in ASP.NET Core using C# that automatically refreshes data after a specific time interval?
Details:
I want to implement a local cache in ASP.NET Core that automatically refreshes data after, say, 5 minutes. The goal is to improve performance and reduce the load on an external data source (such as an API or database) for frequent requests. Additionally, I want to ensure that during the data refresh process, other requests do not access stale data. What is the best way to achieve this in C#?
The goal is to improve performance and reduce the load on an external data source (such as an API or database) for frequent requests. Additionally, I want to ensure that during the data refresh process, other requests do not access stale data.

Check IMemoryCache

This feels like a very open-ended design question without an absolute-correct answer.  One of your requirements specifically stands out as complicated:  The data refresh blocking stale data access.  Let's say the data refresh takes 4 minutes. In that time, a request comes in asking about a piece of data that hasn't been updated yet.  What happens? Does the request WAIT for 4 minutes before completing? Does it fail immediately bc the data is locked? These are implementation details only you can answer based on your specific use case. Off the shelf solutions won't answer those questions for you.

In addition to what others have already said, why 5 minutes? A lot of storage providers now a days can be set up to notify when any data was changed, so if you want a truly efficient caching, you should explore this option first - this way, you only refresh the cache if the data actually changed.

IMemoryCache is a versatile, efficient and simple package you could apply. Here is a simple sample.
DataCacheService.cs
public interface IDataCacheService
{
    Task<T> GetCachedDataAsync<T>(string cacheKey, Func<Task<T>> RetrieveData, TimeSpan Span);
}

public class DataCacheService : IDataCacheService
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;

    public DataCacheService(IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        _cache = cache;
    }

    public async Task<T> GetCachedDataAsync<T>(string cacheKey, Func<Task<T>> RetrieveData, TimeSpan Span)
    {
        //Custom logic...
        return await RetrieveData();
    }
}

DataRefreshService.cs  BackgroundService is needed for automatically refreshing
public class CacheRefreshService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private readonly TimeSpan _span = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    private readonly string _cacheKey = "XXXXX";

    public CacheRefreshService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken Token)
    {
        await Task.Delay(_span, Token);
        var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
        var cacheService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDataCacheService>();

        Func<Task<string>> RetrieveData = async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(200);
            return $"Time Now {DateTime.Now}";
        };

        await cacheService.GetCachedDataAsync(_cacheKey, RetrieveData, _span);
    }
}

Register the service
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDataCacheService, DataCacheService>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<CacheRefreshService>();
builder.Services.AddMemoryCache();



Personally, I like this question, so I guess I’ll present an answer that is surely bad, just to get the ball rolling…
This uses the built-in MemoryCache and uses it to store multiple database records in a Task<Dictionary>. The records are always fetched all together. Depending on your use-case you may not want that.
Obviously all of this should be a read-only situation.
The dependency-injected MemoryCache you get from the framework will be a singleton, so manage your cache keys to be sufficiently unique.
We use the synchronous GetOrCreate() method to return a Task to the caller immediately. This should ensure that concurrent requests wait for the same Task, so the cache isn’t warmed up twice unnecessarily. This should also fulfil your requirement to prevent stale data being returned while the cache is rebuilt (everyone waits until it’s complete).
Like I said, there’s probably all kinds of stuff wrong with this, but at least you got an answer, lol.
Perhaps look into the LazyCache Nuget Package.
public class MyDatabaseRecordService
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache memoryCache;

    private static readonly TimeSpan cacheTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);


    public MyDatabaseRecordService(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        this.memoryCache = memoryCache;
    }
    

    public async Task<MyDatabaseRecord?> Get(int id, bool forceRefresh = false)
    {
        var dict = await getCacheDict(forceRefresh);

        if (dict.TryGetValue(id, out var myRecord))
            return myRecord;
        
        return null; // or refresh cache and see if it’s there now, or whatever
    }


    private Task<Dictionary<int, MyDatabaseRecord>> getCacheDict(bool force)
    {
        if (force)
            memoryCache.Remove("MyUniqueCacheKey");

        return memoryCache.GetOrCreate("MyUniqueCacheKey", async (entry) =>
        {
            entry.SetOptions(new MemoryCacheEntryOptions().SetAbsoluteExpiration(cacheTime));

            return // get your data here
            
        }) ?? Task.FromResult<Dictionary<int, MyDatabaseRecord>>(new());
    }
}

